# How do I make the "%20" in URL's show as "-"

Tags: templating, url, tags, siteurl

I'm building a site where I am linking entries based on their tags. If you click on a tag you go to a dedicated page with all entries that share the same tag.

```
{% for tag in craft.tags.relatedTo(entry) %}
    <li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}tags/{{ tag.title | url_encode }}">{{ tag.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem I have is that if a tag has more than 1 word, the URL displays like this:

`http:/site.com/tag/two%20words`

How do I change "%20" to a dash?

Comment: I've updated my answer below. I'm not sure if you're still having your issue, but would this have solved it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edited**

I just learned this, but as of Craft 2.4, there's a [`kebab` filter](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/filters#kebab) which you can use here. This would probably give you the effect you're after, where the string "two words" would become "two-words", and punctuation characters are dropped by default.

You could use this like so:

```
<li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}tags/{{ tag.title | kebab }}">{{ tag.title }}</a></li>
```

---

**Original**

The `%20` string is being added to replace spaces because you're using the `url_encode` filter on `tag.title`. A simple (though somewhat naïve) way to to solve this would be to use the replace filter:

```
{{ tag.title | url_encode | replace({"%20": "-"}) }}
```

However, you might still see some "%XX" characters in this string if the `tag.title` has other characters that url_encode might want to replace. The "%" character, for example, gets turned into "%25" after being run through `url_encode`.

This also probably won't do what you expect, as the link you're generating for the tag won't work unless you're doing special routing. The problem stems from the fact that tags don't have clean URL slugs at this time, so what you're doing right now is probably the best course of action.

You've probably already seen this, but there's a [documentation page specially about linking to tags](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/tag-urls). This is the current best practice I know of. If you're really looking for cleaner slugs in URLs, I'd recommend using categories instead of tags if possible.